# how can I solve this firebaseAuth error, I have an error adding a new user into firebase

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I get this error everytime I try to register a user on my xamarin app c#

this is my code

```
async void btnRegister_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebAPIkey));
        var auth = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        string gettoken = auth.FirebaseToken;
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", gettoken, "Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
```

this is the error i get:

> Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuthException: 'Exception occured while
> authenticating. Url:
> [https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key={0}](https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=%7B0%7D)
> Request Data: {"email":"18014384@vcconnect.co.za
> ","password":"pass123","returnSecureToken":true} Response: {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalid"
> }
> ]   } }

Comment: Could it be because the email value contains a space at the end?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=FirebaseAuthException+invalid+email+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: It's impossible for us to say more than what the error message also says: it seems the email address you pass to `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` is invalid. I recommend setting a breakpoint on that line, and checking in a debugger what the value is that you're passing.